# Vmware vsphere 7 api

Tags: vmware, vsphere, esxi, vcenter

I am trying to build a python program to automate vmware vsphere task. Currently i am running vsphere 7 esxi server. The problem is when I try to test the api using postman to list the vm's i get an empty array, but I can see the vm information on the vsphere web client without any problem

API call: https://host-ip/rest/vcenter/vm (header contains the session id created using the create session api)

Can someone say why this is happening[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pBqM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately ESXi hosts do not have a REST API service. That service is only available through a vCenter Server. However, you could use the [vSphere Web Services (SOAP) API](https://code.vmware.com/apis/968). Since you reference Python, you could also check out the [pyvmomi](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi) SDK that interacts with that API service.